# How to right-align columns content in reStructuredText simple tables?

Tags: python, alignment, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, tabular

I'm editing the documentation for a project of mine using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), which in turn uses [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) as markup language.

I have a *simple table* (as opposed to *grid table*) in which the rightmost column reports contains numbers that I would like to right-align, but I couldn't find how to achieve that.

```
============  =====================
Event               Score variation
============  =====================
Event 1                        +100
Event 2                         -25
Event 3                        -400
============  =====================
```

I would be happy to switch to a *grid table* if this would allow me to solve the problem.

Comment: reStructuredText doesn't support right alignment of anything. You're be stuck with styling it manually, I think. Good question, though. +1

Comment: @mac What Python version do you use ? And what kind of columns are there in your files: always numbers in the second one ?, always letters at the beginning in first column ?, what kind of separation between first and second column (several blanks ? what minimum number of blanks ? tabs ? given widths ?...)

Comment: @eyquem - Mmm... from the kind of questions, I would guess you misunderstood me... but here are the answers, nevertheless:  2.7.1+ | depends from what .rst file and what table in the file | depends | several blanks | 1.

Comment: @mac _reStructuredText_ not being supporting the feature you want, according to Chris Morgan, I thought that you then must consider to make a special treatment of each file, after its creation, with the help of builtin string's methods or if needed regexes. But the possibility I didn't understand the problem is quite realistic. Do you mean that you would like that the right-alignement should be coded in some special tag or other feature of the _reStructuredText_ document type ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sadly I don't think rst offers that ability... the table styling options are rather limited. That said, if you're rendering to HTML, you could add a custom stylesheet with a css rule such as:

```
table.right-align-right-col td:last-child {
    text-align: right
}
```

and then add the directive:

```
.. rst-class:: right-align-right-col
```

right above your table in the rst file. It's clunky, but it should work.

---

*update 2013-2-6:* I've since needed to accomplish this myself, and came up with a more permanent solution. The [cloud_sptheme.ext.table_styling](https://cloud-sptheme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lib/cloud_sptheme.ext.table_styling.html) Sphinx extension adds directives for doing column alignment, per-column css classes, and number of other table styling tricks. Despite being packaged as part of the "cloud" Sphinx theme, it should work with any Sphinx theme.

Comment: Thank you Eli. I finally chose a theme (agogo) that has ugly tables, so - while I will work my way to improve that, I will use your snippet too.

Answer (score 6):

While it appears that ReST doesn't actually support cell content alignment, you can actually use [line-blocks](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks) within your cell to enforce preservation of whitespace to effectively pad your cell's content.

You'll have to use some of the [unicode-whitespace](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) characters (e.g. `U+2001 - EM QUAD`) and have them preceded by a normal space character (`U+0020`)  i.e. `U+0020U+2001Your String` to stop the ReST parser complaining about malformed tables and unterminated substitution references, etc.

```
+--------+---------+
| String | Num     |
+========+=========+
| foo    ||   12.00|   # second cell's content is actually |<U+0020><U+2001>12.00
+--------+---------+
| bar    ||    3.01|
+--------+---------+
| baz    ||    4.99|
+--------+---------+
| moo    ||   15.99|
+--------+---------+
| quux   ||   33.49|
+--------+---------+
| foo    ||   20.00|
+--------+---------+
| bar    ||  100.00|
+--------+---------+
```

Tables like the above start to look a bit awkward and are awkward to maintain but the approach gets the job done. It also goes without saying, you'll need to both edit and generate UTF-8 output. While `rst2html.py` treats this well, I'm not sure how `sphinx` deals with this and if it can, whether the alignment remains when generating non-HTML documents.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. :) I find it conceptually interesting, but I believe it would be practically very hard to maintain documentation where invisible non-space whitespace is relevant...

Comment: **Absolute madness.** Nobody do this in the real world, please. The new guy will have *no* idea why everything is suddenly ugly, it's Friday night, it's all his fault, and the weekend ahead is now looking grim indeed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the centered directive. I've included an example below:

```
+------+-----------+------------+--------+------+------+
| Type |  .. centered:: -payload-        | crcL | crcH |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+------+------+
| Type | subType   | obj/access | -data- | crcL | crcH |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+------+------+
```

[Here's what that looks like in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS4Lz.png)

Comment: Just realized the title is for right-aligned, not centered... whoops

Comment: Solves _my_ problem thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My approach is a bit of `sed` on the TeX file generated by *Docutils*.
The idea is to replace the `table` declaration with something that fits your needs.

Docutils produce something like that :

```
\begin{longtable*}[c]{p{0.086\DUtablewidth}p{0.290\DUtablewidth}}
```

Imagine you want to right-align the second column.You may want to replace this with :

```
\begin{longtable*}[c]{lr}
```

But you lose the ability to control the width of the cells. What we need here is to declare 2 `\newcolumntype`, one for the right-align (**x**) and one for the left-align (**y**):

```
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{% 
>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}% 
\newcolumntype{y}[1]{% 
>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%
```

And use them in the table declaration:

```
\begin{longtable*}[c]{y{7.5cm}x{2cm}}
```

The `\\` newline must also be replaced with a `\tabularnewline`.

I put everything in a script file because I am on *OSX* and the version of *sed* shipped does not support newline substitution with `\n` (that sucks when you are in a `Makefile`).

### The bottom-line

On OSX/BSD:

```
sed -E -f fix_table.sed < source.tex > destination.tex
```

with `fix_table.sed`:

```
s/\\begin{longtable\*}.*/\\newcolumntype{x}[1]{% \
>{\\raggedleft\\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}% \
\\newcolumntype{y}[1]{% \
>{\\raggedright\\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}% \
\\begin{longtable*}[c]{y{7.5cm}x{2cm}}/
s/\\\\/\\tabularnewline/
```

This is a bit harsh but there is no workaround that really works at the RestructuredText level.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

http://texblog.org/2008/05/07/fwd-equal-cell-width-right-and-centre-aligned-content/

Comment: Thank you. Myself I'm on GNU/Linux, yet +1 for the clear and useful explanation! :)

Comment: This should work on GNU/Linux without the `-E` modifier. And you can use `\n` in Sed instead of real newlines.

Answer (score -1):

As of Docutils 0.13 (late 2016), the [`table` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table) supports an `align` option.

```
.. table::
   :align: right

   ======== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== 
   4 \\ 9    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8  
   ======== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== 
   0         0   28   20   12    4   32   24   16    8  
   -------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
   1         9    1   29   21   13    5   33   25   17  
   -------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
   2        18   10    2   30   22   14    6   34   26  
   -------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
   3        27   19   11    3   31   23   15    7   35  
   ======== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ====
```

Your stylesheet will need to support the [`.align-right` class](https://github.com/docutils-mirror/docutils/blob/e88c5fb08d5cdfa8b4ac1020dd6f7177778d5990/docutils/writers/html4css1/html4css1.css#L155-L186)

Comment: This right-aligns the entire table, doesn't it? The question is about right-aligning the values in the rightmost column.

Comment: Nope. It right aligns the values in each cell, but the table is left aligned. See the table rendered at https://www.georgevreilly.com/blog/2019/09/15/use-for-octal.html

Comment: I am referring to the default behaviour of Sphinx and Docutils, without any CSS customizations. I tried the "read_the_docs", "nature" and "classic" themes. With the `:align: right` option, the whole table is right-aligned, not the values in the cells.