# Alignment in csv-table does not work when I use reStructuredText and Sphinx to generate PDF

Tags: csv, pdf, alignment, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want the words in the center in the csv-table when I use sphinx and reStructuredText and Sphinx. I use the align:center, but it does not work. The words are still left.

[image: The source text in reStructuredText]
[image: PDF generation]

Sphinx Version:sphinx-build 5.1.1
Python Version：Python 3.10.6

I want to have the words are in the center of the table when the align tag is set as "center".

Comment: I think `align` is for the table as a whole, not the items in the table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to right-align columns content in reStructuredText simple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348208/how-to-right-align-columns-content-in-restructuredtext-simple-tables)

Comment: @mzjn，but if the table width is set, the align tag is not useful. 

Comment: @StevePiercy, thanks for your information. The answer does not answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, but reStructuredText does not support aligning content within a CSV table cell. You must use CSS, as shown in the link I shared earlier.